# About font appointment

Tags: css

I found this css

```
body {
font: 13px/1.231 arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
*font-size: small;
*font: x-small;
}
```

What is 1.231?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value `1.231` is the value for the [`line-height` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) (see the [`font` shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/fonts.html#font-shorthand) for further information). The number without a unit refers to the element’s font size.

Comment: yes that's the line-height property value, as given and explained here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/18/7-principles-of-clean-and-optimized-css-code/ For more explaination of font styling see this image: http://media2.smashingmagazine.com/images/clean-optimized-code/figureB.gif